# MySQL InnoDB Crash

Tags: mysql, innodb

Last night the server was upgraded from a MySQL server with InnoDB Cpanel have much of a problem when MySQL server will shut down! Because many of the sites on vps in their database to InnoDB Engine Table Does not have put up their site and say

```
error: Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'
```

Error

Log into mysql server gives an error ...

```
121109 16:13:45 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
121109 16:13:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 7 log sequence number 119077976
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 1 log sequence number 87578807
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 2 log sequence number 87619303
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 11 log sequence number 87417771
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 54 log sequence number 87698770
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 5 log sequence number 87534070
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 6 log sequence number 87619339
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 45 log sequence number 87575389
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 59 log sequence number 87682843
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 1 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 1D9800
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 0 log sequence number 87619851
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
InnoDB: Cleaning up trx with id 1D96B2
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 8 log sequence number 87615596
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 264 log sequence number 87698228
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: table 'nicecity_zz/fireshop_admin'
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 325,
InnoDB: but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have
InnoDB: you deleted or moved .ibd files?
InnoDB: This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
InnoDB: whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the
InnoDB: table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Error: page 267 log sequence number 87698793
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 86849548.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
121109 16:13:45  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 3086341824 in file btr/btr0pcur.c line 430
InnoDB: Failing assertion: btr_page_get_prev(next_page, mtr) == buf_block_get_page_no(btr_pcur_get_block(cursor))
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
12:43:45 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=536870912
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=4000
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 256251 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x25)[0x84b4f05]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x38c)[0x82ef45c]
[0xf52420]
[0xf52402]
/lib/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x50)[0x196df0]
/lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x101)[0x198701]
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so[0x4391eb]
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so[0x4647a2]
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so[0x4f9205]
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so[0x47ea8e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x34)[0x82e1814]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x836847f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x784)[0x836a9a4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x81f9c13]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(main+0x4f5)[0x81fb015]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc)[0x183e9c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x81417e1]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
121109 16:13:45 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.server.com.pid ended
```

It will enable the mysql server With **skip-innodb** , But the problem is not resolved to the users!

The mysql command

```
show engines;
```

the following result :

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB     | NO      | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to ensure that the system time is set correctly. And ensure that it stays set correctly by running the ntp daemon.

Second, you need to [follow the link given in the error message you posted](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) and begin recovering the databases.

Comment: time has update ... And innodb_file_recovery tested But the problem is not resolved to the users!